# Can react native use jQuery

Tags: jquery, react-native

I am migrating my phonegap apps into react-native.

Since my phonegap apps use a lot of jQuery plugins, so I am curious if react-native can use jQuery.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nope. JQuery heavily relies on HTML DOM and CSS where react-native has their own DOM-like native view hierarchy with their own style implementation which is similar to subset of CSS (flex-box) but it is implemented differently.

Just to put it in perspective - React-Native app is NOT an HTML/Hybrid app - it's a native app with logic controlled by Javascript and using react patterns with virtual view hierarchy representation. The only common part with web apps is Javascript engine (no CSS/HTML). Phonegap apps are Hybrid HTML apps using web views so they can use frameworks/plugins that are not pure javascript but tied to HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thank you Jarek. 
Right now I am using plugins like [intltelinputs](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input.git) in phonegap apps, but I  can't find relative components like it for react-native. Frustrating!

Comment: @LeoChen It's important to know that React Native is only in `0.8` right now and not fully released. If there isn't a component or node module that handles something, you'd have to build it yourself.

Comment: @GoldenBeet, thanks for the suggestion...I know react native is still very young at this stage, I will consider to build it by my own.