# If I have linux and a not perfectly functioning hackintosh, should I use reactnative or phonegap for building multiplatform (android, ios) apps?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, react-native

I have the following considerations:

1.I will never use the hackintosh on a regular basis, maybe only for the final steps on xcode and publishing.

2.It could be that some functionalities i would like to realize cannot be done on phonegap/react native. I heard react native allows one to integrate native codes (e.g. android with java and ios with swift), but I'd like to reconfirm this.

3.I read that many people were complaining about errors with react native on linux even for android. Can someone perhaps tell me if they have already successfully built something with react native + linux?

4.I haven't spent much time on learning react native yet, so this last point might be silly, but if one already have build an android app with react native, how much work is there still to build ios? Also, do I HAVE TO use jquery for react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll try and answer as thoroughly as possible, from the RN side (I've never really used cordova).

> 1. I will never use the hackintosh on a regular basis, maybe only for the final steps on xcode and publishing.

OK, RN works with all platforms. Of course, you will need xCode at one point to publish your app but apart from that everything can be done on other platforms. However, to build on iOS, you will need Xcode to launch the simulator or run you app in debug mode so you will need to work on a Mac.

> 2. It could be that some functionalities i would like to realize cannot be done on phonegap/react native. I heard react native allows
>      one to integrate native codes (e.g. android with java and ios with
>      swift), but I'd like to reconfirm this.

Yes ! RN allows the integration of native code. Check the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html#content) for more information.

> 3. I read that many people were complaining about errors with react native on linux even for android. Can someone perhaps tell me if they
>      have already successfully built something with react native + linux?

Can't help on this one but RN works with linux, especially the latest versions. Check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html)

> 4. I haven't spent much time on learning react native yet, so this last point might be silly, but if one already have build an android
>      app with react native, how much work is there still to build ios?
>      Also, do I HAVE TO use jquery for react native?

I have built apps for iOS and Android and have never used jQuery in any of them. Moreover, jQuery **does not** work with react-native as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805245/can-react-native-use-jquery)
Finally, about 80% of the code (depending on apps of course) is the same between android and iOS. This leaves 20% to work on (usually not long modifications).

Hope this helps, but I strongly recommend using RN instead of phone gap.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!