# can I use jquery in react native?

Tags: jquery, ajax, react-native, get

can I use ajax in a reactive native app? if not how can I perform the similar command using fetch?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://test.com/api",
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "text",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data)

        });
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805245/can-react-native-use-jquery. You should use fetch. There are polyfills available.

Comment: Refer this for how to use ferch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Hi @AravindS , thanks , I had a look at that earlier , but I cant seem to find a way to replicate the crossDomain , xhrFields , username and pass using fetch

I only found credentials: 'include'   but whee do I add the user and pass ?

Comment: i will comment on fetch api sample get request. in btw what is this usernamr and pass? are they query params to the URL?

Comment: when you use : xhrFields: {withCredentials: true }, it will prompt the user for user and pass but having them in the request will do that automatically

Comment: To cause browsers to send a request with credentials included, even for a cross-origin call, add credentials: 'include'..more here https://github.github.io/fetch/#credentials

Comment: thanks for taking the time and helping out , how will I prive the user and pass when i use credentials: 'include'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176164/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-nero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a sample fetch API for getting data and more [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/this-api-is-so-fetching/)

```
return fetch(
      "URL",
      {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('username:password'),
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "User-Agent":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25",
          "x-correlation-id": "asfsef4243sdf",
          "x-channel": "android"
        },
        method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("got json" + response);
        response.json();
      })
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log("Hey = "+responseJson);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```