# "Type Error: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function" in react-native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use jQuery to pull xml data from an internal website. I have a basic expo project setup that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import $ from 'jquery';

import {XML_DATA_URL} from './src/api/constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  fetchData = () => {
    return $.ajax({
          url: XML_DATA_URL,
          dataType: 'xml',
    });
  }

  render() {
    let response = 'test';
    response = this.fetchQviewData();
    console.log(response);
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this code I receive the error **"TypeError: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function"**. Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "exp start --lan",
    "android": "exp start --lan --android",
    "ios": "exp start --ios",
    "eject": "exp eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
     29.0.0.tar.gz",
    "yarn": "^1.9.4"
  }
}
```

My environment is visual studio code and when I hover over the function I can see the prototype:

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure what's happening (I used a jQuery <script> instead of the package in my early React stuff), but I'd recommend using the `fetch()` API instead.

Comment: I would like to us the fetch() API but unfortunately there are some http content on the website I'm trying to reach so the fetch() call throws an error saying "the page at [code line number] was loaded over https, but requested an insecure resource" fetch only supports https request.

Comment: It is not the fetch command that creates the error. Check whether the server ssl configured and if yes, then check if your url is "http://" then change it to "https://"

Comment: If I am sure, then the problem is that you are returning the ajax call, Try to return the response recieved in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found that answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805245/can-react-native-use-jquery), the issue seems to be that because react-native uses a virtual DOM and there is no actual html or css then jQuery won't work because it needs access to the DOM.