# Import javascript library into React Native

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native

I have a javascript library in my project.
This library need external jquery libraries like this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.signalR.js"></script> 
<script src="myLibrary.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to use this library on my React Native project?
Can I import jquery into my project?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need jQuery in a React application? Also, you can publish your library to NPM and import it through there.

Comment: I migrate from javascript to react native. myLibrary is a third party library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use jQuery with react-native.

> JQuery heavily relies on HTML DOM and CSS where react-native has their
>   own DOM-like native view hierarchy with their own style implementation
>   which is similar to subset of CSS (flex-box) but it is implemented
>   differently.
>
> Just to put it in perspective - React-Native app is NOT an HTML/Hybrid
>   app - it's a native app with logic controlled by Javascript and using
>   react patterns with virtual view hierarchy representation. The only
>   common part with web apps is Javascript engine (no CSS/HTML). Phonegap
>   apps are Hybrid HTML apps using web views so they can use
>   frameworks/plugins that are not pure javascript but tied to HTML/CSS.
>   source : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805245/can-react-native-use-jquery)