# jQuery requires a window with a document in vue native

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vue-native

i ran the `npm install jquery --save` command to install jquery in my vue native project but i still getting this error `jQuery requires a window with a document`

in my template:

```
   <view >  
        <touchable-opacity class="button" :on-press="test">
          <text class="loginText">login</text>
        </touchable-opacity>
      </view>
```

in my script:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

Vue.use(Vuex);


export default {
  data:()=>({
     loginObj: {
      memberCode: '',
      password: '',
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    test(){
        $(".button").css("display", "none");
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah,Vue Native is a wrapper around the React Native APIs. JQuery heavily relies on HTML DOM where vue-native and react-native have their own DOM-like native view.they are differently.And you can use JQuery in a vue web project,not a vue-native app project.

refer to [vue-native](https://vue-native.io/docs/react-native.html) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805245/can-react-native-use-jquery)

thanks.