# why is onPress not working on expo client

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, react-native, expo

i am trying to send a request using jQuery when the button is pressed, it is working on the snack but on expo client it is giving me an error `undefined is not a function (near '...jquery.default.ajax...')` but it is not giving me this on the web

here is the code:

```js
<Button title='Submit' onPress={() => {
         $.ajax({
           url: 'https://modern-clinic.herokuapp.com/new/case',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
             name: this.state.name,
             paid: this.state.price,
             description: this.state.desc,
             assigned: this.state.assigned,
             date: this.state.date
           },
           success: function(res){
             console.log(res)
           },
           error: function(err){
             console.log('error')
             console.log(err)
           }
         })
        }}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default New
```

> put the data you want in it but paid should be a number

it is working all good on the web and sending requests as it should but on expo client especially for android it is not working but i didn't try expo client for IOS

Comment: Add your imports for clarity but you should definitely use Axios or another HTTP client rather than jQuery which is built for the browser. As a plus, React Native doesn't produce DOM-based code.

Comment: Ok Thanks Alot You Had Helped Me Out 

Comment: In this case, feel free to validate the answers by clicking the up triangle ;-) It will help others find them.

Comment: Ok Just Vote The Question And I Will Vote The Answers Because I Need 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS/React Native uses virtual DOM unlike jQuery which relies of HTML DOM, so it will not work in React Native App.

You can use `fetch` api or `axios` instead.

You can read more about it here: [Can react native use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31806221/5669120)